# WebService log4j exception

Tags: web-services, log4j

I am getting a wacky exception from a web service when deployed on our development server, but not when running on my RAD WebSphere localhost.

The exception happens within the catch block where I am doing the following:

```
    } catch(RuntimeException e) {
        log.error("While enqueue(" + candidate.getBpCode() + ", " + candidate.getGeneratedBy() + ")", e);
        throw e;
    }
```

So it seems like an exception happens, it reached the log.error() statement, and something about that is blowing up with that very odd exception.  I have good reason to believe that candidate is not null, and neither are the returns of those two methods.

It's complaining about category.  We do use category in our log4j config, but this works fine locally, and in past server deployments.  Anyone have any idea what is going on here?

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: org/apache/log4j/spi/ThrowableInformation.<init>(Ljava/lang/Throwable;Lorg/apache/log4j/Category;)V
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:190)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:123)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:120)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:90)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:119)
at $Proxy31.enqueueCandidate(Unknown Source)
at gov.usdoj.afms.enote.test.queue.QueueWSTest.testQueueService(QueueWSTest.java:119)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Can you confirm `candidate` is not null?  Granted, I'd expect a NPE instead of what you're getting, but you never know.

Comment: I can.  We have a null test that goes through a different code path.